# When matter is created using the google api in python the matter id is not null

Tags: python-3.x, google-vault-api

We used the google api using pythin to create matter... It got created and we can see it in the browser but when I try and run a export to it  I cannot use this matter as the matter id is null for matter created in our account.  I dont see api to SET the matter id.  How do we go about resolving this.  All API's using matter needs matter id

Created matter using below code:
def create_matter(service):
    matter_content = {
      'name': 'NGMTEST',
      'description': 'Matter Test using API',
    }

```
matter = service.matters().create(body=matter_content).execute()

return matter
```

querying the matterusning the quickstart.py provided by google I get this...

C:\Temp\vault\quickstart>python quickstart.py
Matters:
NGMTEST (None)

Answer (score 0):

The matter id should be automatically populated when you call create.

Does this happen for every call to create matter?